# Typescript - Filtering data from a Kendo DataSource

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, typescript, datasource

I'm having an issue where I need to check to see if an object with a specific ID is present in a Kendo DataSource object. I want to use filter on it, as such:

```
var howMany = self.dsItems.data().filter(function (item) {
    return item.ID == currentItem.ID;
}).length;
```

The problem is that `self.dsItems.data()` returns an array of `Object`, so I get a syntax error saying that the data type `Object` doesn't have an `ID` property. Is there a way to cast it to the correct data type, or ignore the error?

Comment: this mentions that you can use .toJSON() to convert the data array object to a javascript array.. then you might be able to use the property names. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observablearray#tojson    `self.dsItems.data().toJSON().filter()`

Comment: That worked perfectly, you're beautiful, don't ever change.